# QGIS Plugins - DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, python-2.7, 64bit, 32bit

This is my first question so please go easy.
I am trying to develop a Plugin for QGIS. I made my plugin using the "plugin builder", then compiled the .qrc and .ui files with PySide-rcc.exe and PySide.uic.py respectively. This all seems satisfactory.

However, my first problem arises when the plugin loads as the QGIS and Python (PySide) libraries are not in the same place.

```
ImportError: No module named PySide
```

I resolved this by adding a reference to the PySide path at the start of the compiled .ui module:

```
Import sys
Sys.path.append("C:\\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages")
```

Unfortunately when I run it again I get the critical error:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Google searches are leading me to believe that this is caused by an incompatibility between 32bit and 64bit modules, however, I cannot easily download different versions as they are supplied under my companies IS policy.

This seems to apply to all the QGIS modules as i can not access any modules even from the python console:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append("C:/Program Files (x86)/Quantum GIS Lisboa/apps/qgis/python")
>>> for path in sys.path:
print path

C:\Windows\system32
C:\Python27\Scripts
D:\HRW\VET\HrwPyLibs
D:\HRW\VET\HrwPyLibs\Xdmf
D:\HRW\VET\HrwPyLibs\Converters
C:\Python27\python27.zip
C:\Python27\DLLs
C:\Python27\lib
C:\Python27\lib\plat-win
C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk
C:\Python27
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:/Program Files (x86)/Quantum GIS Lisboa/apps/qgis/python
>>> from qgis.core import QgsFeatures

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
from qgis.core import QgsFeatures
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Has anyone else experienced this problem or is there an obvious issue that i have not noticed?

Thanks,

Chris

Running: Windows 7 (64bit), Python 2.7.2 (64bit), QGIS 1.8.0 (???)

Comment: actually this i have noticed that this happens in the console as described above, which is 64bit. But that when it happens in QGIS the python being used is 32bit - presumably QGIS is also 32bit.

Comment: Urgh,
Ok, i now see that my company have issued me with 64bit Python and modules and 32bit QGIS with 32bit Python and modules. Seemingly there is a compatibility between the modules available to each as running the

    from qgis.core import QgsFeatures

in the QGIS python console yeilds no problems - however, i still need to build my ui and qrc files.

Time to lobby the IT department for 32bit PySide installed into the QGIS module directory.

Comment: You shouldn't be using pyside or your own Python install.  QGIS comes with it's own Python27 install and PyQt4 which has pyucc4